# How to define a function in SMT 2.0 which returns the minimal value of 4 parameters

Tags: z3, smt

I'd like to define a function in SMT 2.0 that returns the minimal of 4 integer values.

Comment: What did you try? For which programming language?

Comment: Also, why did you put the smt tag on there? Hover over the box to see what that tag supposedly means here; that doesn't sound related to your question at all.

Answer (score 5):

The `min4` function (the minimal of 4 integer values) can be defined in the SMT 2.0 language as:

```
(define-fun min2 ((a Int) (b Int)) Int
    (ite (<= a b) a b))

(define-fun min3 ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int)) Int
    (min2 a (min2 b c)))

(define-fun min4 ((a Int) (b Int) (c Int) (d Int)) Int
    (min2 a (min3 b c d)))
```

The following link contains an example using this function:
http://rise4fun.com/Z3/wuyU

In SMT 2.0, `define-fun` is essentially a macro definition. SMT 2.0 language does not support the definition of functions expecting arbitrary number of arguments. You may consider using programmatic APIs for SMT solvers such as [Scala^Z3](http://lara.epfl.ch/~psuter/ScalaZ3/), [SBV](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/sbv) and [Z3Py](http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/tutorial/guide). They are much more convenient to use than SMT 2.0.
Here is the same example in Z3Py: http://rise4fun.com/Z3Py/2vy

Comment: For reference purposes, here's how to do it using Haskell/SBV: http://gist.github.com/2353312